# How to Straighten Arch-Shaped Mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I have been attempting for several hours now to "unbend" this teeth model with little luck. The goal is to place all the teeth along a single plane with minimal deformation to them or the gums.

So far i have attempted many curve modifier deformations, but most end up in disaster. Unfortunately each tooth needs to still be a separate mesh at the end of this process.

What do you think you would do to achieve this?
Thank you so much for your help.

Here is the model file if it might be of assistance https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a_uuDKqHhfvP1Tu1N0fQDOYP7lYzmU5G/view?usp=sharing

[image]